# Slow file close on windows server 2016

Tags: java, windows

I installed windows server 2012 and 2016 on one pc by multi-booting, but 2012 is fast and 2016 is slow.
What is the cause?
As a result of various checks, it is not a java version problem.
The file write source code is as follows.

```
try {
    FileWriter fwriter = null;
    BufferedWriter bwriter = null;

    fwriter = new FileWriter(filepath, mode);
    bwriter = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);
    bwriter.write(contents);
    bwriter.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    if (fwriter != null)
        fwriter.close();
    if (bwriter != null)
        bwriter.close();
}
```

Comment: [look at this - probably your 2016 server has write cache disabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/940032/disc-write-cache-on-windows-domain-controller-always-disabled-by-default)